# How to play audio in background with firefox os?

Tags: audio, permissions, html5-audio, lockscreen, firefox-os

In my manifest file I've add the audio-channel-content in permissions:

```
"permissions": {
    "audio-channel-content":{"description":"Use the audio channel for the music player"}
}
```

In my index.html I've got an audio tag like:

```
<audio mozaudiochannel="content" preload="none" src="http://my-stream-url"></audio>
```

I can play my audio stream during 2mn:

- The first one when the phone is unlock.
- After 1mn my phone auto-lock the screen and it continue playing for another minute.

Does it possible to play this audio stream more than 1mn after the lock?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The code and permission block you have are correct and I can confirm it is working in Firefox OS 1.1. You can also do the whole thing in Javascript:

```
audio = new Audio();
audio.preload = 'none';
audio.mozAudioChannelType = 'content';
```

Comment: Is Boot2Gecko 1.2.0.0-prerelease equal to Firefox OS 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the wifi is closed after screen shutdown (auto-lock)?

Are you using the dev version of gaia? Wifi is set to always connect in product version.

Comment: I'm using a geeksphone peak with boot2Gecko 1.2.0.0-prerelease.

I don't know if wifi is disconnected on phone lock

Comment: 1.2.0.0-prerelease is a development version.