# how do I play a mp3 file from my application while in background?

Tags: javascript, firefox-os, audio-player

I am doing a podcast manager application for Firefox OS. So far I managed to download files and save them on the sdcard. For playback I am using MozActivity because I want the file to be played in an installed music player.

Here is the code for playback:

```
var activity = new MozActivity({

    name: "open",

    data: {
      type: [
        "audio/mpeg",
        "audio/ogg",
        "audio/mp4"
      ],
      // here I pass the file blob
      blob: data
    }
  });
```

The problem is that when I put the app in background to open another one, the playback stops and the music player is closed.

Another thing I would like to do, is when I play again a file that I did not finished listening, to resume the playback from the minute I left it.

Comment: have you seen this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/App_development_FAQ#How_can_I_play_music_in_the_background.3F

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895835/how-to-play-audio-in-background-with-firefox-os

Comment: I would rather prefer to not handle playback myself. But if there's no other solution, I will implement that.
Thanks!

Comment: I did it. I don't remember how. I need to take a look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add this in the manifest file

```
"permissions": {
    "audio-channel-content": {
      "description": "Required to play audio in the background."
    }
}
```